# Python routine on matrix diagonalization

Tags: python, routines

Good morning!
I have a doubt about the python routine at:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html&ved=2ahUKEwjJxrid8ezoAhXj6eAKHQbzBCwQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw29YNiM2xotOUio89RVOe_x&cshid=1587038068544

It says that it computers k eigenvectors and eigenvalues, with k smaller than matrix dimension, but is it possible to use it to get the lowest k eigenvalues or are those eigenvalues randomly ordered in the spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) you linked states, the keywords **`which`** and **`mode`** affects which eigenvalues are selected:

```
*which* : str ['LM' | 'SM' | 'LA' | 'SA' | 'BE']

Which k eigenvectors and eigenvalues to find:
'LM' : Largest (in magnitude) eigenvalues 
'SM' : Smallest (in magnitude) eigenvalues
...
```

and

```
*mode* : string ['normal' | 'buckling' | 'cayley']

...
The choice of mode will affect which eigenvalues are selected by the keyword 'which'.
```

---

The default of **`which`** is `'LM'` (largest eigenvalues) so you might want to pass `'SM'` to retrieve the lowest.